# Replacing capacitor with more than but close to farad value

Tags: capacitor

I have a crushed capacitor rated at 25V 390 microfarads. My local electronics store has a 25V 470 microfarad capacitor available.

Is this a safe replacement? I believe you are fine with increasing the voltage rating, but I am not sure about the capacitance rating.

With extremely basic DC knowledge, why is this OK or not OK?

Comment: It depends on what is the purpose of the capacitor in the circuit, or what parameters are important. It might be that ESR is more important than capacitance, so how do you know what are the parameters of the original capacitor in order to find a suitable replacement?

Comment: A capacitor that has had it's housing compressed/dented into the point it looks crushed but not popped.

Comment: That would be a "crushed capacitor" rather than a "crush capacitor". JRE has fixed your question for you.

Answer (score 0):

The safest option would be to order the same capacitor from digikey, mouser or another distributor. This will ensure that you do not alter the function of the circuit.

As for what will happen if you use a different value, given that this is an electrolytic capacitor, there is a good chance that this is a power filtering or similar application where a slightly larger would probably work. You'd have to look at the details of the specific circuit to be sure however.